# Вывод сообщения на консоль в проектах C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Cоздал CLR проект на C++ В Visual Studio 2017, и есть там какие нибудь функции чтобы выводить на экран сообщение или что то другое?

Comment: Вы меня неправильно поняли, я хочу получить список функций для CLR проектов на C++

Comment: [Класс Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывод сообщения на консоль в CLR

```
Console::WriteLine("text");
```

Для паузы после окончания можно использовать

```
Console::ReadLine();
```

Вообще CLR очень похож на C#

Comment: Можно же ещё использовать `cout` при подключенной библиотеке `iostream`, а также стандартный `printf`, нет? Это если я правильно вопрос понял. Консольное приложение специфических рамок не накладывает

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev Я давно писал на CLR, и на сколько помню то Console::WriteLine так же является "стандартным" выводом. printf - ближе к C чем к CLR